# Why is it needed to cast a generic type when a where constraint should be enough

Tags: c#

Let's start with the following taxonomy

```
public abstract class Automobile { }

public class Automobile<T> : Automobile where T : Automobile { }

public class Car : Automobile<Car> { }
public class Truck : Automobile<Truck> { }

public class SmartAutomobile<T> : Automobile<T>
{
    public T MyAutomobile { get; set; }

    public SmartAutomobile(SmartTechnology smart)
    {
        // Cannot implicitly convert Automobile to T
        this.MyAutomobile = AutomobileFromSmart(typeof(T), smart);
    }

    public static Automobile AutomobileFromSmart(Type type, SmartTechnology smart)
    {
        if (type == typeof(Car))
            return new Car { /* ... */ };
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException("Car type " + type.FullName + " not recognized");
    }
}

public class SmartTechnology  { }
```

As you can see from the comment, the compiler says it cannot convert an `Automobile` to `T` in `SmartAutomobile<T>`'s constructor. How can this be? the compiler should know that `T`, because of the constraint in `Automobile<T>` , **is** an `Automobile`.

If I try to explicitly cast it

```
this.MyAutomobile = AutomobileFromSmart(typeof(T), smart) as T;
```

I get the compiler error

> The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint

Now if I also define the `where` constraint in `SmartAutomobile<T>`

```
public class SmartAutomobile<T> : Automobile<T> where T : Automobile
```

The compiler doesn't show any error

But if I remove the explicit cast:

```
this.MyAutomobile = AutomobileFromSmart(typeof(T), smart);
```

The *Cannot implicitly convert Automobile to T* error shows up again.

How can it be that the compiler  doesn't realize the `where` constraint forces `T` to be an `Automobile`?

Comment: You are not constraining it to `class`.

Comment: Since you want to cast it *actually cast it*.  You're not performing a cast.

Comment: by the way, C# has compiler not interpreter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can it be that the interpreter doesn't realize the where constraint forces T to be an Automobile?

No, it forces `T` to be *derived from* `Automobile`.  And since down-casting is not always safe, you can't implicitly cast from `Automobile` to `T`.  If `T` was `Car`, but `AutomobileFromSmart` returned a `Truck`, then the cast would fail at runtime.  You can *explicitly* cast (or use `as`) which tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing, and this cast will be safe at run-time").

Comment: So in this specific implementation it is completely safe to cast it to `T`?

Comment: With what you have at the moment now, yes, but the compiler does not dig deep enough to know that.  Plus the method is `public` so there's no guarantee that someone else won't call it with a different type.

Answer (score 4):

Variance.

Your constraint says that `T` is *derived* from `Automobile`. That doesn't mean that `T` *is* an `Automobile` - it could also be a class derived from `Automobile`. And now you have a situation where a variable that should always be of type `MyAutomobile` is of type `Automobile` instead - that's a complete violation of the type system.

So you can pass `T` anywhere you can pass an `Automobile`, but it doesn't apply vice versa - just like you can pass `Label` instead of `Control`, but not vice versa.

Your second problem is that generic constraints aren't inherited. You do have to mention them everywhere they are required. That's why `SmartAutomobile<T>` still needs the same constraint that's also in `Automobile<T>`.